# Using Sheet Codename with Workbook-

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from the tab of one workbook to the tab of another.  I want to get the row count from the workbook that I am copying **from** but the code is in the workbook I am copying **to**.  My code is as follows:

'''
rowCount = Workbooks(reportbook).Sheet1.Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'''

I get an "Object does not support this property or method" error.  I want to use the sheet's Codename (Sheet1) instead of the Index (Sheets(1)) or Name ("Sheet 1").  Using the Index and Name both give no error but the name and/or order of the sheets might change in the workbook I copying from.

It seems that trying to specify which of the two workbook I want to look for Sheet1 in is causing the issue.  If I remove "Workbooks(reportbook)" then the code works but counts from the wrong workbook.

Comment: you cannot use the code name from other workbooks.  There are work around hacks if you google it, but I would not recommend them..

Comment: If you are going to use one of the linked duplicates, I would recommend the answer by @TimWilliams.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you.  I need to get better at searching for answers.