# cant set ws by sheet code when my code is in my personal.xlsb folder

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the following code from the actual excel it works.
But when I run it from my personal.xlsb folder it doesn't work.

```
sheet code is shQty
sheet name is Qty
```

```
Sub refv2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Assuming the workbook is open
    Set wb = Workbooks("audit.xlsx") ' Replace "WorkbookName.xlsx" with the name of your workbook
    ' Assuming the worksheet is named "Sheet1"
    Set ws = wb.shQty

    wb.Activate
    ' Select the worksheet
    ws.Select
   
End Sub
```

Comment: A worksheet saved as a variable `shQty` already has the workbook attached.  Change to `Set ws = wb.WorkSheet("Qty")`

Comment: You cannot use the code name of a sheet in a different workbook unless  you set a reference to the workbook with the sheet in it, which is usually more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: If a user changes the name of the worksheet will the codeName shQty still work?

Comment: You can use the `RefWorksheetByCodeName` function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76614705) in [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbjSg.png).